# Why does dataframe read and plot fully in IDE but not when ran in terminal? (python)

Tags: python, dataframe, matplotlib, plot, ide

I have a very simple scipt do read a csv and plot using pandas and matplotlib.

When it is ran in PyCharm it reads all the rows (only around 425), but when ran in terminal it only reads 3 lines and plots that.

Does anyone have an idea why?

Here is my code:

```
import pandas
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pandas.read_csv('data.csv', delimiter=',',names=['Value', 'Date'])
print(df)

df.plot(kind='scatter', x='Date', y='Value')

plt.show()
```

Comment: Please format your code

Comment: A guess here, but how do you run it n a terminal? Do you have more than one data.csv file? (I assume you think it only reads 3 lines because your `print(df)` only prints 3 lines?

Comment: @doctorlove A run it with the path of my python and then the path of the script. It both only plots and prints 3 data points and that's why I think it's only reading 3. (That could be the wrong assumption?)

Comment: Try changing the name of the csv file and putting the full path in? (I suspect it's reading a different file)

Comment: Thanks so much, I put the full path in and that worked. I should work on filenames in future :D

Comment: I'll put in an answer for completeness

Answer (score 0):

It's very easy to end up with more than one file called "data.csv", so you can end up with your IDE using a different file to the file used on a prompt.

One way round this is to give the full path for any file you open.

You can also check where the debugger in your IDE is running - there will be an option for the current working directory.